# Intellij IDEA support for underscore.js templates

Tags: javascript, templates, intellij-idea, underscore.js

Here is exist plugin to support underscore.js templates in Intellij IDEA?

For now it looks like this:

[image]

System tags <%= is not highlighted and html tags is highlighted as wrong

Answer (score 10):

There is a JetBrains supported IntelliJ plugin for [EJS](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7296) which is what you want.  It is available in the Plugins Tab on Settings with the Browse Repositories.   It is also available for the PHPStorm/Webstorm/RubyMine/PyCharm IntelliJ derivatives.  It works pretty well, it has a few minor glitches as it is still early in development and will definitely do what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't been updated since its release. More buggy and outdated now than initially (using with PhpStorm 9).